# pkg-config errors when compiling cgo program with Mingw64

Tags: mingw, mingw-w64, cgo, msys2

I'm trying to compile a cgo program that uses ffmpeg in a Mingw64 environment. I'm getting errors from `pkg-config` saying it can't find the ffmpeg libraries:

```
$ go build -x src/github.com/imkira/go-libav/examples/transcoder.go
WORK=C:\msys64\tmp\go-build616922114
mkdir -p $WORK\b033\
cd c:\users\chris_000\code\go\src\github.com\imkira\go-libav\avfilter
pkg-config --cflags -- libavfilter libavutil
mkdir -p $WORK\b030\
cd c:\users\chris_000\code\go\src\github.com\imkira\go-libav\avcodec
pkg-config --cflags -- libavcodec libavutil
# pkg-config --cflags libavfilter libavutil
Package libavfilter was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libavfilter.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libavfilter' found
Package libavutil was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libavutil.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libavutil' found
pkg-config: exit status 1
```

But when I run `pkg-config` from the shell it works fine:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags -- libavfilter libavutil
-I/mingw64/include
$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig:/mingw64/share/pkgconfig
```

I am using the Mingw64 environment from MSYS2. I did a clean install of MSYS2 (on Windows 10) then installed the following packages:

```
$ pacman -S pkg-config mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-ffmpeg
```

The Go program I am trying to install is `examples/transcoder.go` from `https://github.com/imkira/go-libav`. My Go version is `go1.10.1 windows/amd64`.

NB: `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is exported from the shell, and `libavutil.pc` and `libavcodec.pc` are present in `/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two versions of `pkg-config`. Installing `mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config` fixed the issue:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config
```

No idea why the version of `pkg-config` I had already installed worked from the shell but not from cgo.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. I had also installed the normal `pkg-config`, and it caused the same issues that you had.